# Google crawl error increase, it shows me weird mix in all the url's in magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento, url, indexing, robots.txt

Magento 1.9.0.1

Hi, 
I have since 10 days an increase in 404 errors on webmaster tools, and in the crawl error section i found 150 weird url that make no sense :
http://sitename.com/ (cms page)/index.php/(another cms page or product).

In my memory i haven't change anything, but this has to come from somewhere. I've checked `robot.txt` (i only deleted prior to that the line `User-agent: Googlebot-Image Disallow:` ), htaccess , `local.xml` and friendly url in `system/config/web`. Looks all good.

Here is a screenshot : [image]

In my robot.txt i've got :

```
Disallow: /index.php/ <br>
Disallow: /*.css$ <br>
Disallow: /*.php$ <br>
Disallow: /*?p=*& <br>
Disallow: /*?SID= <br>
Disallow: /?___from_store= <br>
Disallow: /*___from_store= <br>
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Regards, 
Marc

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because Stack Overflow is a [programming-related](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) Q&A site. Your question is not about programming. Perhaps you should post it on http://magento.stackexchange.com instead?

Comment: Hi Enigmativity, thanks for your response.Your funny ;) When you type "magento" in the search box you get a thousand results about Q&A around magento error 500/seo/coding... etc. Make it a programming answer by helping me to find a way to code my robot.txt or htaccess in order to redirect those url back to the homepage.

Comment: I'm just letting you know what the [help/on-topic] says.

Answer (score 0):

I just found out in my access.log that i had an attack to my /downloader folder : 
"GET /downloader/index.php?A= HTTP/1.1" 200 2518 "-" "-"65.98.60.146 - - [07/Mar/2016:12:37:45 +0100] 
"POST /downloader/ HTTP/1.1" 302 - "-" "-".

And after every 100 attacks i get the URL error that appear : 
"GET /bache-tendue/index.php/tendeur-elastique/tendeur-caoutchouc/tendeur-caoutchouc-25cm HTTP/1.1" 404 111180 "-" "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; AhrefsBot/5.0; +http://ahrefs.com/robot/)"

Hope this helps.

Regards, 
Marc

Comment: Every time you see an unauthorized IP address issuing a PUT against /downloader/ you can just take it as a given that someone is doing a brute force attack against your website and is trying to break into the backend. It's why I find it so offensive when people harp on doing the security-by-obscurity change on the /admin/ url and leave the downloader login screen wide open. Block both /downloader/ and /admin/ to only allow access from your VERY MINIMAL SET of admin IPs and this issue goes away.

Comment: Hi Fiasco, thanks for your response. I've block external access to both "Downloader/" and "Admin/" via the htaccess with my IP adress. Hope this helps a least for the bute force attack. I'm now trying to find an answer on this weird url in google webmaster tool.